# hook_block and rendering a form in content section

Tags: blocks, forms

Basically, I have tabs on my modules admin page, I need to show a different form per page.
The node type and forms have been created and the first form on `block[0]` shows correctly, while the first part of `block[1]` shows correctly, it also icludes some fields from `block[0]` and this shouldn't be so.

Here is my `hook_block`, maybe someone can spot my mistake and point it out to me.

```
function svm_mail_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {

switch ($op) {
  case 'list':
    $blocks = array(
      0 => array(
        'info' => t('Add New Account'),
        'status' => 1,
        'region' => 'content',
        'visibility' => 1,
        'pages' => array('admin/settings/svm-mail/add-account'),           
        ),
      1 => array(
        'info' => t('Update Mail Statistics'),
        'status' => 1,
        'region' => 'content',
        'visibility' => 1,
        'pages' => array('admin/settings/svm-mail/ymlp/update'),
        )
      );
    return $blocks;
    break;

  case 'view':
    if(user_access('create mail account')) {
    switch ($delta) {
      case 0:
        //render node form from http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/6
        module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
        $node_type = 'svm_mail_account';
        $form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';
        global $user;
        $node = new stdClass();
        $node ->uid = $user->uid;
        $node ->name = (isset($user->name) ? $user ->name: '');
        $node ->type = $node_type;
        $block['subject'] = t('Add New Account');
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form($form_id,$node);
        dvm($block);
        return $block;
        break;
      case 1:
        module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
        $node_type = 'svm_mail_groups';
        $form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';
        global $user;
        $node = new stdClass();
        $node ->uid = $user->uid;
        $node ->name = (isset($user->name) ? $user ->name: '');
        $node ->type = $node_type;
        $block['subject'] = t('Update Mail Statistics');
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form($form_id,$node);
        dvm($block);
        return $block;
        break;
    }
    break;
}
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using my case statements for my form entities, I forgot to add in a break;

It all works nicely now!!